# web application security mapping to weblogic

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, configuration, weblogic

I have web application which is deployed to weblogic server.

its part of web.xml is here:

```
  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>private</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/private/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
        <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
        <http-method>PUT</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>
            AppAdmins
        </role-name>
        <role-name>
            AppUsers
        </role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<security-role>
    <role-name>AppAdmins</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role>
    <role-name>AppUsers</role-name>
</security-role>
```

weblogic.xml:

```
<security-role-assignment>
    <role-name>AppUsers</role-name>
    <principal-name>Users</principal-name>
</security-role-assignment>

<security-role-assignment>
    <role-name>AppAdmins</role-name>
    <principal-name>Admins</principal-name>
</security-role-assignment>
```

my deployment security policies:

[image: sec policy]

I have created AppAdmins and AppUsers roles in the weblogic administration console inside the global roles and configured them to use Users and Admins security groups. But this doesn't work, weblogic keeps saying Unauthorized error. What's the problem? Thanks

upd:
I added some fixes to web.xml and weblogic.xml but nothing works anyway. updated topic with new settings

added strange stacktrace, it looks like server trying to authorize my user but then transaction fail happens o.o

server log:
http://textuploader.com/allne

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the correct solution of the problem for me.

Problem was that my security data provider was tagged as 'sufficient' and default one as 'required' so the second was overriding my db security provider results and auth failed.

Choosing 'required' on my security provider and 'optional' on default works fine